# Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, rxjs, es6-promise

I'm using async and promise like given below, I want to wait for the `img` value to be returned.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
 ...
 ... 
 this.auth.msg.subscribe((res) => {
   let img=this.fetchImage(this.user.id);
   this.url=img; // getting error 
   ...
 });  
}   

async fetchImage(Id) {
  let result: any;
  let payload = {
    Id: Id
  };
  result = await this.Sev.getPicture(payload).toPromise();
  return result.response;
}
```

When I pass `img` response to some other variable getting this error:

> Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'string'

Comment: Please review your code and provide a minimal reproducible example. From your code, you are calling `fetchImage` method but you didn't show us, do you mean `fetchProfileImage`?

Comment: @YongShun Sorry for the wrong method name can you pls check now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message mentions that your `fetchImage` returns a Promise.

To get the value from the Promise, either:

1. A callback function

```
this.auth.msg.subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.fetchImage(this.user.id)
    .then((value) => {
      this.url = img;
    });
});
```

2. Use async/await

```
this.auth.msg.subscribe(async (res: any) => {
  let img = await this.fetchImage(this.user.id);
  this.url = img;
});
```

While `.toPromise()` is deprecated from RxJS 7. Recommend migrating the `.toPromise()` with `firstValueFrom`/`lastValueFrom` as stated in the [RxJS documentation](https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise):

```
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';

async fetchImage(Id)
{
  let result: any;
  let payload = {
    Id: Id
  };
  result = await lastValueFrom(this.Sev.getPicture(payload));
  return result.response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try switchMap

```js
this.auth.msg.pipe(
  switchMap(_ => this.fetchImage(this.user.id))
).subscribe((img) => {
  this.url=img;
  ...
});
```